# R code to get the previous hour slots non null value

Tags: r

The input table is given below. New column need to be created taking the previous non null row `Value` considering the latest `Hour_slot` prior to the current row `Hour_Slot` grouping by `ID`

| ID | Hour_slot | X | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 2:00:00 | 1 | 16 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 3:00:00 | 1 | 13.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 4:00:00 | 1 | NA |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 5:00:00 | 1 | 4.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 23:00:00 | 1 | 12 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 24:00:00 | 1 | 8.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 4:00:00 | 2 | 11.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 5:00:00 | 2 | 12 |

Output:

| ID | Hour_slot | X | Value | output_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 2:00:00 | 1 | 16 | NA |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 3:00:00 | 1 | 13.5 | 16 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 4:00:00 | 1 | NA | 13.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 5:00:00 | 1 | 4.5 | 13.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 23:00:00 | 1 | 12 | 4.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 24:00:00 | 1 | 8.5 | 12 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 4:00:00 | 2 | 11.5 | 13.5 |
| id1 | 2023-04-01 5:00:00 | 2 | 12 | 13.5 |

Sample R code:

```
df[, output_Value:=shift(value, type="lag"), by= ID]
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% fill(output_Value)
```

The above code is not considering the Hour_Slot. There is a chance of having two rows with same `Hour_slot`. I need the previous hour slot non-null value as `output_Value`

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show the example data

Comment: Could you clarify how you are getting the output values? You say group by `ID`, but your example data only have one `ID`, so not much help. Where do the 13.5 values for `output_Value` come from in the final two rows?

Comment: Row no. 7, the hour slot is 2023-04-01 4:00:00, So I need to take the Value from the previous hour slot : '2023-04-01 3:00:00' in row no. 2. Hence the output_Value of row no. 7 is 13.5.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use a series of `dplyr::mutate()` and `tifyr::fill()` transformations:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(output_Value = case_when(row_number(Hour_slot) == 1 ~ Value),
         .by = c(Hour_slot, ID)) %>%
  mutate(output_Value = lag(output_Value)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill(output_Value, .direction = "down") %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(output_Value = head(output_Value, 1), .by = c(Hour_slot, ID))
```

Output:

```
   ID           Hour_slot X Value output_Value
1 id1 2023-04-01 02:00:00 1  16.0           NA
2 id1 2023-04-01 03:00:00 1  13.5         16.0
3 id1 2023-04-01 04:00:00 1    NA         13.5
4 id1 2023-04-01 05:00:00 1   4.5         13.5
5 id1 2023-04-01 23:00:00 1  12.0          4.5
6 id1 2023-04-02 00:00:00 1   8.5         12.0
7 id1 2023-04-01 04:00:00 2  11.5         13.5
8 id1 2023-04-01 05:00:00 2  12.0         13.5
```